# Android HTTP Link stop reading when there is a " ",() ,etc

Tags: android

I try to send the user key in String  to onine server and make request, but it just send the string before the symbols. Any idea how to make Android **read through** but **not remove** the symbols? I mean all the symbols.

[image: The link sent to online server from android]

The following method is replace the [space] so the PHP can read my link

```
String sText = ""+autoTv.getText().toString().replace(" ","%20")+"";
SearchRequest t = new SearchRequest();
t.execute(sText);
```